# How do I create a new column by matching a variable with another variable and have it repeat until the first variable changes in R?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, reticulate

| receptor | year | month | day | hour | hour.inc | lat | lon | height | pressure | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 19 | 0 | 31.768 | -106.501 | 500.0 | 835.6 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 18 | -1 | 31.628 | -106.350 | 508.8 | 840.5 | 2018-01-03 18:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 17 | -2 | 31.489 | -106.180 | 526.2 | 839.4 | 2018-01-03 17:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 16 | -3 | 31.372 | -105.974 | 547.6 | 836.8 | 2018-01-03 16:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 15 | -4 | 31.289 | -105.731 | 555.3 | 829.8 | 2018-01-03 15:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 14 | -5 | 31.265 | -105.462 | 577.8 | 812.8 | 2018-01-03 14:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 13 | -6 | 31.337 | -105.175 | 640.0 | 793.9 | 2018-01-03 13:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 12 | -7 | 31.492 | -104.897 | 645.6 | 809.2 | 2018-01-03 12:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 11 | -8 | 31.671 | -104.700 | 686.8 | 801.0 | 2018-01-03 11:00:00 |
| 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 10 | -9 | 31.913 | -104.552 | 794.2 | 795.8 | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 2018 | 1 | 4 | 19 | 0 | 31.768 | -106.501 | 500.0 | 830.9 | 2018-01-04 19:00:00 |
| 2 | 2018 | 1 | 4 | 18 | -1 | 31.904 | -106.635 | 611.5 | 819.5 | 2018-01-04 18:00:00 |
| 2 | 2018 | 1 | 4 | 17 | -2 | 32.070 | -106.749 | 709.7 | 808.0 | 2018-01-04 17:00:00 |
| 2 | 2018 | 1 | 4 | 16 | -3 | 32.223 | -106.855 | 787.3 | 794.9 | 2018-01-04 16:00:00 |

Above is what my dataframe looks like but I am trying to create a new column called date1 and will look like the frame below.

```
 receptor year month day hour hour.inc    lat      lon height pressure                date       date1
1         1 2018     1   3   19        0 31.768 -106.501  500.0    835.6 2018-01-03 19:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
2         1 2018     1   3   18       -1 31.628 -106.350  508.8    840.5 2018-01-03 18:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
3         1 2018     1   3   17       -2 31.489 -106.180  526.2    839.4 2018-01-03 17:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
4         1 2018     1   3   16       -3 31.372 -105.974  547.6    836.8 2018-01-03 16:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
5         1 2018     1   3   15       -4 31.289 -105.731  555.3    829.8 2018-01-03 15:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
6         1 2018     1   3   14       -5 31.265 -105.462  577.8    812.8 2018-01-03 14:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
7         1 2018     1   3   13       -6 31.337 -105.175  640.0    793.9 2018-01-03 13:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
8         1 2018     1   3   12       -7 31.492 -104.897  645.6    809.2 2018-01-03 12:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
9         1 2018     1   3   11       -8 31.671 -104.700  686.8    801.0 2018-01-03 11:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
10        1 2018     1   3   10       -9 31.913 -104.552  794.2    795.8 2018-01-03 10:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
38        2 2018     1   4   19        0 31.768 -106.501  500.0    830.9 2018-01-04 19:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
39        2 2018     1   4   18       -1 31.904 -106.635  611.5    819.5 2018-01-04 18:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
40        2 2018     1   4   17       -2 32.070 -106.749  709.7    808.0 2018-01-04 17:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
41        2 2018     1   4   16       -3 32.223 -106.855  787.3    794.9 2018-01-04 16:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
```

Disregard  the index furthest to the left. I want to match the receptor (Ex:1,2) with the first occurrence of the date (Ex: 2018-01-03 19:00:00,2018-01-04 19:00:00) and then repeat till the receptor changes.

I'm working in R so I'd like to find a solution in R but I could also use a python solution and make use of the Reticulate package in R.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` you can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) #converting into data.frame 
df[,date1 := date[1],receptor] # taking the first date per receptor
df

#Output 

    receptor year month day hour hour.inc    lat      lon height pressure                date               date1
 1:        1 2018     1   3   19        0 31.768 -106.501  500.0    835.6 2018-01-03 19:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
 2:        1 2018     1   3   18       -1 31.628 -106.350  508.8    840.5 2018-01-03 18:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
 3:        1 2018     1   3   17       -2 31.489 -106.180  526.2    839.4 2018-01-03 17:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
 4:        1 2018     1   3   16       -3 31.372 -105.974  547.6    836.8 2018-01-03 16:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
 5:        1 2018     1   3   15       -4 31.289 -105.731  555.3    829.8 2018-01-03 15:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
 6:        1 2018     1   3   14       -5 31.265 -105.462  577.8    812.8 2018-01-03 14:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
 7:        1 2018     1   3   13       -6 31.337 -105.175  640.0    793.9 2018-01-03 13:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
 8:        1 2018     1   3   12       -7 31.492 -104.897  645.6    809.2 2018-01-03 12:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
 9:        1 2018     1   3   11       -8 31.671 -104.700  686.8    801.0 2018-01-03 11:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
10:        1 2018     1   3   10       -9 31.913 -104.552  794.2    795.8 2018-01-03 10:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
11:        2 2018     1   4   19        0 31.768 -106.501  500.0    830.9 2018-01-04 19:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
12:        2 2018     1   4   18       -1 31.904 -106.635  611.5    819.5 2018-01-04 18:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
13:        2 2018     1   4   17       -2 32.070 -106.749  709.7    808.0 2018-01-04 17:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
14:        2 2018     1   4   16       -3 32.223 -106.855  787.3    794.9 2018-01-04 16:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
```

Comment: This is clean. Really impressed my Team Lead today. I don't work with extremely large datasets so I don't use Datatable much. But this is the second solution I have seen to a problem using DT. I did not take credit for this btw. Said that boi Chriss Paul got me.

Comment: Thank you @bob0901. Sometimes I find `data.table` so handy for this kind of problems that is always my first choice, and actually I am able to handle large datasets with it too.

Answer (score 0):

Try filling location of the unchanged value with `np.nan` and changed value location with `date` (of that index) and then simply do forward fill using `.ffill()`

`df.receptor.shift().ne(df.receptor)` will give you where the receptor value changes. compare the previous and current value to see the change.

```
df['date1'] = np.where(df.receptor.shift().ne(df.receptor), df.date, np.nan)
df.date1 = df.date1.ffill()
```

---

|  | receptor | year | month | day | hour | hour.inc | lat | lon | height | pressure | date | date1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 19 | 0 | 31.768 | -106.501 | 500.0 | 835.6 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 18 | -1 | 31.628 | -106.350 | 508.8 | 840.5 | 2018-01-03 18:00:00 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 17 | -2 | 31.489 | -106.180 | 526.2 | 839.4 | 2018-01-03 17:00:00 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 16 | -3 | 31.372 | -105.974 | 547.6 | 836.8 | 2018-01-03 16:00:00 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 4 | 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 15 | -4 | 31.289 | -105.731 | 555.3 | 829.8 | 2018-01-03 15:00:00 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 5 | 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 14 | -5 | 31.265 | -105.462 | 577.8 | 812.8 | 2018-01-03 14:00:00 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 6 | 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 13 | -6 | 31.337 | -105.175 | 640.0 | 793.9 | 2018-01-03 13:00:00 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 7 | 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 12 | -7 | 31.492 | -104.897 | 645.6 | 809.2 | 2018-01-03 12:00:00 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 8 | 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 11 | -8 | 31.671 | -104.700 | 686.8 | 801.0 | 2018-01-03 11:00:00 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 9 | 1 | 2018 | 1 | 3 | 10 | -9 | 31.913 | -104.552 | 794.2 | 795.8 | 2018-01-03 10:00:00 | 2018-01-03 19:00:00 |
| 10 | 2 | 2018 | 1 | 4 | 19 | 0 | 31.768 | -106.501 | 500.0 | 830.9 | 2018-01-04 19:00:00 | 2018-01-04 19:00:00 |
| 11 | 2 | 2018 | 1 | 4 | 18 | -1 | 31.904 | -106.635 | 611.5 | 819.5 | 2018-01-04 18:00:00 | 2018-01-04 19:00:00 |
| 12 | 2 | 2018 | 1 | 4 | 17 | -2 | 32.070 | -106.749 | 709.7 | 808.0 | 2018-01-04 17:00:00 | 2018-01-04 19:00:00 |
| 13 | 2 | 2018 | 1 | 4 | 16 | -3 | 32.223 | -106.855 | 787.3 | 794.9 | 2018-01-04 16:00:00 | 2018-01-04 19:00:00 |

Comment: Be sure to avoid period qualifiers for column referencing to avoid conflict with attributes (i.e., `df['receptor']`, `df['date1']`). See warning in [Attribute Access](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider base R's `ave` after calculating a `Date` column to return first date time per date grouping using `head`:

```r
df <- within(df, {
  date_short <- as.Date(substr(as.character(date), 1, 10), origin="1970-01-01")
  first_dt_hour <- ave(date, date_short, FUN=function(x) head(x, 1))
  rm(date_short)   # DROP HELPER COLUMN
})

print(df)
#    receptor year month day hour hour.inc    lat      lon height pressure                date       first_dt_hour
# 1         1 2018     1   3   19        0 31.768 -106.501  500.0    835.6 2018-01-03 19:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
# 2         1 2018     1   3   18       -1 31.628 -106.350  508.8    840.5 2018-01-03 18:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
# 3         1 2018     1   3   17       -2 31.489 -106.180  526.2    839.4 2018-01-03 17:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
# 4         1 2018     1   3   16       -3 31.372 -105.974  547.6    836.8 2018-01-03 16:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
# 5         1 2018     1   3   15       -4 31.289 -105.731  555.3    829.8 2018-01-03 15:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
# 6         1 2018     1   3   14       -5 31.265 -105.462  577.8    812.8 2018-01-03 14:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
# 7         1 2018     1   3   13       -6 31.337 -105.175  640.0    793.9 2018-01-03 13:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
# 8         1 2018     1   3   12       -7 31.492 -104.897  645.6    809.2 2018-01-03 12:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
# 9         1 2018     1   3   11       -8 31.671 -104.700  686.8    801.0 2018-01-03 11:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
# 10        1 2018     1   3   10       -9 31.913 -104.552  794.2    795.8 2018-01-03 10:00:00 2018-01-03 19:00:00
# 38        2 2018     1   4   19        0 31.768 -106.501  500.0    830.9 2018-01-04 19:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
# 39        2 2018     1   4   18       -1 31.904 -106.635  611.5    819.5 2018-01-04 18:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
# 40        2 2018     1   4   17       -2 32.070 -106.749  709.7    808.0 2018-01-04 17:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
# 41        2 2018     1   4   16       -3 32.223 -106.855  787.3    794.9 2018-01-04 16:00:00 2018-01-04 19:00:00
```

**Data**

```r
data <- ' receptor year month day hour hour.inc    lat      lon height pressure                date
1         1 2018     1   3   19        0 31.768 -106.501  500.0    835.6 "2018-01-03 19:00:00" 
2         1 2018     1   3   18       -1 31.628 -106.350  508.8    840.5 "2018-01-03 18:00:00" 
3         1 2018     1   3   17       -2 31.489 -106.180  526.2    839.4 "2018-01-03 17:00:00" 
4         1 2018     1   3   16       -3 31.372 -105.974  547.6    836.8 "2018-01-03 16:00:00"
5         1 2018     1   3   15       -4 31.289 -105.731  555.3    829.8 "2018-01-03 15:00:00"
6         1 2018     1   3   14       -5 31.265 -105.462  577.8    812.8 "2018-01-03 14:00:00"
7         1 2018     1   3   13       -6 31.337 -105.175  640.0    793.9 "2018-01-03 13:00:00"
8         1 2018     1   3   12       -7 31.492 -104.897  645.6    809.2 "2018-01-03 12:00:00"
9         1 2018     1   3   11       -8 31.671 -104.700  686.8    801.0 "2018-01-03 11:00:00"
10        1 2018     1   3   10       -9 31.913 -104.552  794.2    795.8 "2018-01-03 10:00:00"
38        2 2018     1   4   19        0 31.768 -106.501  500.0    830.9 "2018-01-04 19:00:00"
39        2 2018     1   4   18       -1 31.904 -106.635  611.5    819.5 "2018-01-04 18:00:00"
40        2 2018     1   4   17       -2 32.070 -106.749  709.7    808.0 "2018-01-04 17:00:00"
41        2 2018     1   4   16       -3 32.223 -106.855  787.3    794.9 "2018-01-04 16:00:00"'

df <- read.table(text=data, 
                 colClasses=c(rep("integer", 7), rep("numeric", 4), "POSIXct"),
                 header=TRUE)
```